# system.data.dataset.EnableContraints Exception with no network connection

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, web-services

I have a web service which is backed by a local database, when the machine hosting this is connected to a network all is well, when I disconnect the network cable and access the same web method I get an exception:

```
2014-11-19 13:46:24,151 DEBUG  Sage.Client.Core.Web.ActionFilters.LogExceptionsAttribute System.Data.ConstraintException: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
at System.Data.DataSet.EnableConstraints()
at System.Data.DataSet.set_EnforceConstraints(Boolean value)
at System.Data.DataTable.EndLoadData()
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DoLoadDataSet(IDbCommand command, DataSet dataSet, String[] tableNames)
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.LoadDataSet(DbCommand command, DataSet dataSet, String[] tableNames)
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.LoadDataSet(DbCommand command, DataSet dataSet, String tableName)
at Sage.MMSAdmin.DBLayer.SessionHelper.GetSession(String sessionIdentifier)
at Sage.MMSAdmin.DBLayer.SessionHelper.SessionInfo(String sessionIdentifier)
at Sage.MMSAdmin.DBLayer.SAA.SAAAPI.GetSessionContextData(String sessionID)
at Sage.MMS.SAA.Client.InProcessProxy.SAAInProcessProxy.GetSessionContextData(String sessionID)
at Sage.Client.Core.Web.ActionFilters.RequiresValidCompanyAttribute.FetchContextData(String sessionID)
at Sage.Client.Core.Web.ActionFilters.RequiresValidCompanyAttribute.ValidateSession(ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, HttpContextBase httpContext)
at Sage.Client.Core.Web.Attributes.ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
```

which seems to be with authentication, however I cannot see why this would fail without a network connection yet work successfully with.

The DB is SQLServer2012.

Any suggestions or pointer would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the data in the table, there was a null value in a field that is marked as NOT NULL, as such the dataAdapter could not be filled with this data and threw an exception as the existing data did not satisfy the constraints set on the table (data model).

The problem was caused by straight to sql code being used to insert data into the table, so the constraints were not checked by the code before the data was inserted (additionally the data may have existed before the constraint)